# Getting word count of doc/docx files in R

Tags: python, r, ms-word

I have a stream of doc/docx documents that I need to get the word count of.

The procedure so far is to manually open the document and write down the word count offered by MS Word itself, and I am trying to automate it using R.

This is what I tried:

```
library(textreadr)
library(stringr)
myDocx = read_docx(myDocxFile)
docText = str_c(myDocx , collapse = " ")
wordCount = str_count(test, "\\s+") + 1
```

Unfortunately, `wordCount` is NOT what MS Word suggests.

For example, I noticed that MS Word counts the numbers in numbered lists, whereas `textreadr` does not even import them.

Is there a workaround? I don't mind trying something in Python, too, although I'm less experienced there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reading the docx files with a different library (the `officer`) and, even though it doesn't agree 100%, it does significantly better this time.

Another small fix would be to copy MS Word's strategy on what is a Word and what isn't. The naive method of counting all spaces can be improved by ignoring the "En Dash" (U+2013) character as well.

Here is my improved function:

```
getDocxWordCount = function(docxFile) {

    docxObject = officer::read_docx(docxFile)
    myFixedText = as.data.table(officer::docx_summary(docxObject))[nchar(str_trim(text)) > 1, str_trim(text)]
    wordBd = sapply(as.list(myFixedText), function(z) 1 + str_count(z, "\\s+([\u{2013}]\\s+)?"))
    return(sum(wordBd))

}
```

This still has a weakness that prevents 100% accuracy:
The `officer` library doesn't read list separators (like bullets or hyphens), but MS Word considers those as words. So in any list, this function currently returns X words less where X is the number of listed items. I haven't experimented too much with the attributes of the `docxObject`, but if it somehow holds the number of listed items, then a definite improvement can be made.

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to be done using the `tidytext` package in R.

```
library(textreadr)
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

#read in word file without password protection
x <- read_docx(myDocxFile)
#convert string to dataframe
text_df <-tibble(line = 1:length(x),text = x)
#tokenize dataframe to isolate separate words
words_df <- text_df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word,text)
#calculate number of words in passage
word_count <- nrow(words_df)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to disagree with you there. If you compare the proposed code to what I tried, you will see that ```identical(x, myDocx)``` rreturns ```TRUE```. The proposed library reads the text in the exact same way. You do suggest an alternative way of counting the words, but this can also never agree with MS Word, since the input is inherently different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_Word_File <- "D:\\text.docx"
doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_Word_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$Words()$Count()
```